# My dropdown navigation bar is not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu where it will display images once you hover over the menu item called Tournaments, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I suspect there might be something wrong with these `CSS` instructions:

```
.menu ul li .submen
.menu ul li: hover .submen
```

but I'm not able to identify the error.

Here is the nav `CSS` and `HTML`:

```css
.menu_wrap{
  width: 100%;
}

.menu{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.menuimg a img{
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

.menu ul{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #282933;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.menu ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d43a5b;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: block;
}

.menu ul li .submen{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
  width: 80%;
  right: 10%;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  line-height: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu ul li: hover{
  background: #169cc3; 
}

.menu ul li: hover .submen{
  visibility: visible; 
}

.submen .col img{
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layers.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tacks1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu_wrap">
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="menuimg">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="Images/dragon.png"></a>
      </div>
      <nav class="navv">
        <div  class="navup">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="Login.php">Log In</a></li>
            <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="navdown">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="tickets.php">Tickets</a></li>
            <li><a href="tournaments.php">Tournaments</a></li>
              <div class="submen">
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="images/dragon2.png">
                  <h5>Tournament</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="images/dragon2.png">
                  <h5>Tournament</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <img src="images/dragon2.png">
                  <h5>Tournament</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            <li> <a href="#">Players</a></li>
            <li><a href="Meritorder.php">Meritorder</a></li>
            <li><a href="sponsers.php">Sponsers</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About SAKDC</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>  
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
    <!-- All content____________________________________________________________________-->
  <div class="bodystuff">
```

Comment: The CSS script thats not working as far as I can tell is the following 2: .menu ul li .submen; and .menu ul li: hover .submen

Comment: Can you add the CSS and HTML and JS (if there) in a single code snippet.

Comment: i have only used css and html and that's all coding there is to it, The only other page linked to it is the style sheet that so far only contains the body css in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

- write submenu code inside `<li></li>` tag.
- do not space between tag and hover `.menu ul li: hover` instead this try `.menu ul li:hover`

```css
.menu_wrap{
  width: 100%;
}

.menu{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.menuimg a img{
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

.menu ul{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #282933;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

.menu ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #d43a5b;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bolder;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  display: block;
}

.menu ul li .submen{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
  width: 80%;
  right: 10%;
  padding: 25px 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  line-height: 20px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu ul li:hover{
  background: #169cc3; 
}

.menu ul li:hover .submen{
  visibility: visible; 
}

.submen .col img{
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
          <div class="menu_wrap">
          <div class="menu">
            <div class="menuimg">
              <a href="index.php"><img src="Images/dragon.png"></a>
            </div>
            <nav class="navv">
              <div  class="navup">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="Login.php">Log In</a></li>
                  <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="navdown">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="tickets.php">Tickets</a></li>
                  <li>
                       <a href="tournaments.php">Tournaments</a>
                       <div class="submen">
                         <div class="col">
                           <img src="images/dragon2.png">
                           <h5>Tournament</h5>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col">
                           <img src="images/dragon2.png">
                           <h5>Tournament</h5>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col">
                           <img src="images/dragon2.png">
                           <h5>Tournament</h5>
                         </div>
                       </div>
               </li>
                  <li> <a href="#">Players</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Meritorder.php">Meritorder</a></li>
                  <li><a href="sponsers.php">Sponsers</a></li>
                  <li><a href="about.php">About SAKDC</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>  
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but I don't see any changes to the code.

Comment: <div class="submen">....</div> is inside <li></li> tags.

- in css ".menu ul li: hover" don't give space between ".menu ul li:hover" because hover is not working properly